# Display Value and Label for Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) Select

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am currently trying to display both the value and the label for Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) by using their documentation here: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/select/

Currently only the label will display.

In the ACF plugin tool for choices it says:

> Enter each choice on a new line.
>
> For more control, you may specify both a value and label like this:
>
> red : Red

So I entered the following:

```
free : Free License
```

To display the value and label I entered my field name:

```
<?php
$field = get_field_object('license_type');
$value = $field['value'];
$label = $field['choices'][ $value ];

echo 'Value: ' . $value . '<br>' . 'Label: ' . $label;
?>
```

This only displays the value like so:

```
Value: Free Licence
Label:
```

Which seems wrong I believe that should actually be the label.

What I should or I want to display is:

```
Value: free
Label: Free License
```

It seems pretty straight forward but I must be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2):

What you will need to do is when you define the Select field, select the Return Format as 'Both (Array)'.

This means you can then call your field as a variable and echo the label and value:

```
$field = get_field('license_type');
$value = $field['value'];
$label = $field['label'];

echo 'Value: ' . $value . '<br>' . 'Label: ' . $label;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Let me know if this helps at all

Comment: i search for a solution, how can i output the selected part to a shortcode?